# Can clients pick a Muslim ruler if the server has Sword of Islam?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

My understanding is that clients will be able to use the DLCs of the host, even if they themselves don't have them.

For instance, I've tried enabling Sons of Abraham, and everyone was able:

- to join the game
- to ask gold to the Jews

What isn't clear to me if this boon is *exactly* like having that DLC, i.e. you could pick Muslim rulers if the host has Sword of Islam, or it's just for the "related" features but does not extend to character selection.

Answer (score 2):

The Sword of Islam DLC unlocks nothing but the ability to play as Muslims - all other features of the "expansion" - mechanics for Muslim characters, mostly - are actually a free part of the 1.06 patch, and are already a part of all up-to-date CK2 games.

The server needs to own and have active the Sword of Islam DLC for any player to play Islamic characters. Other players don't need to own the DLC to play Islamic characters.